# Django CMS on Raspberry Pi 3 Fails

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, django-cms

Today I tried to install django CMS for a while on my Raspberry pi but it will not work. I Installed a fresh "RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE" then I entered following commands via an ssh connection:

```
sudo wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo pip install Django==1.10
sudo pip install virtualenv
cd /srv
sudo mkdir django_cms
cd django_cms
sudo virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install djangocms-installer
sudo mkdir django_site
cd django_site/
sudo djangocms -f -p . web_site
```

All this follows this [guide](https://django-cms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/install.html)
And this error get thrown after executing the last command above:

```
    Creating the project
Please wait while I install dependencies
ERROR: cmd : [u'pip', u'install', u'-q', u'django-cms>=3.5,<3.6', u'djangocms-admin-style>=1.2,<1.3', u'django-treebeard>=4.0,<5.0', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-file/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-style/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-googlemap/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-snippet/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-picture/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-video/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'easy_thumbnails', u'django-filer>=1.3', u'Django<2.0', u'pytz', u'django-classy-tags>=0.7', u'html5lib>=0.999999,<0.99999999', u'Pillow>=3.0', u'django-sekizai>=0.9', u'six'] :Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-FFzxtb/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CPB18v-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-FFzxtb/Pillow/

The installation has failed.


*****************************************************************

Check documentation at https://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.io

*****************************************************************

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 33, in execute
    verbose=config_data.verbose
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djangocms_installer/install/__init__.py", line 95, in requirements
    output = subprocess.check_output(['pip'] + args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[u'pip', u'install', u'-q', u'django-cms>=3.5,<3.6', u'djangocms-admin-style>=1.2,<1.3', u'django-treebeard>=4.0,<5.0', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-file/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-style/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-googlemap/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-snippet/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-picture/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-video/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/archive/master.zip?1520455195.14', u'easy_thumbnails', u'django-filer>=1.3', u'Django<2.0', u'pytz', u'django-classy-tags>=0.7', u'html5lib>=0.999999,<0.99999999', u'Pillow>=3.0', u'django-sekizai>=0.9', u'six']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Does anyone of you have an solution for this?

(My Python version: 2.7.13)

Comment: Try running the pip install command that fails directly on the shell, without `-q` (which means quiet), to see the output.

Comment: Which one do you mean? I cant figure out which command of the array fails

Comment: The last line in the output, starting with `subprocess.CalledProcessError`. You have to turn that python list into a command, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is the Pillow installation that is failing. You need to install the python development libraries first

```
# Python 2
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools

# Python 3
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools
```

There are some other prerequisites you'll have to install as well. The Pillow docs give the following prerequisites for Ubuntu 14.04. I'm not sure what the equivalents are for Raspian Stretch

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev \
libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev \
tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

See the [Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.0.0/installation.html#linux-installation) for more information.

Since you're starting a new project, allow me to encourage you to use Python 3!

Instead of running the Django CMS installer, I would try to get Pillow to install by itself. If it fails, then the error message should be more obvious.

```
pip install Pillow
```

If the latest version fails, you could try 3.0, since that seems to be the minimum version for Django CMS.

```
pip install 'Pillow==3.0'
```

Comment: I installed the dev Tools like you said but after I run "source env/bin/activate" and "sudo djangocms -f -p . web_site" still the same error comes up

Comment: It looks like there are some other prerequisites you need to install. I can't help with the specifics.